# How to apply function to each cell in a cell array which contains 3D Matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, mean, cell-array, variance

I have a cell array A, of dimension say `1x8` and each cell consist of `10x13xN`matirx(numerical values).

Example:

`10x13x91 double    10x13x91 double 10x13x91 double 10x13x91 double 10x13x91 double 10x13x91 double 10x13x91 double 10x13x91 double`

now i want to take mean and variance for 10x13(130 Values) across N. i.e, (1,1,1)(1,1,2)...(1,1,N). first 2 values indicates the points and the third one refers to the position.

When i try to apply mean over a 1x8 Cell array of the same dimension and cell values as mentioned above using the `cellfun` function, i get the following error.

`A = 1x8 cell`

`B = cellfun(@mean,A)`

`Error using cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.`

i need the results like only 260 values(mean+variance) across 8 elements of 1x8 Cellarray,by the way i can ignore the N values, since i take the mean and variance over N.
How can i do this?
Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate more clearly on what you want to do? You have 8 matrices with size 10x13x91. Do you want to have a mean value for every 10x13 matrix? That will give you a 1x91 long vector for every cell. Is that your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `@mean`, use `@(x)mean(x,3)`, and as the others have mentioned - `...,'UniformOutput',false`.

Since the results of the computation always have the same size (`10x13`), you can convert the resulting cell to a numeric array, if you [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) `B` to be a vector in the 3<sup>rd</sup> dimension:

```
C = cell2mat(reshape(B,1,1,[]));
```

Now, if you also want to compute variance while you're at it, you can do 
something like

```
B = cellfun(@(x)cat(3,mean(x,3),var(x,0,3)),A,'UniformOutput',false);
```

But if you want this last *B* as a numeric array, you'd need to make it a vector in the 4<sup>th</sup> dimension (since the 3<sup>rd</sup> was taken by the [concatenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html)):

```
C = cell2mat(reshape(B,1,1,1,[]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help @Dev-iL,now i get a 10x13x2 double in each cell with `val(:,:,1)` as mean and `val(:,:,2)` as variance a total of 260 values,now my final  doubt is how can i make this `10x13x2` double as a `260x1` or `1x260` matrix in each cell, such that it becomes like `(m1,v1) and (m2,v2) ...(Mn,Vn)` .(i.e) i want to concatenate these values of mean and variance together, Kindly Suggest, Thanks.

Comment: @DeepakEevilPersonified you should read the documentation of the `reshape` function, which I linked. To turn anything into a column vector you can use `out = reshape(in,[],1);`.

Answer (score 0):

The output from `cellfun` is not the same in every cell, so you need to write `B = cellfun(@mean,A,'UniformOutput',false)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question. I think the code sequence you want is:

```
B = cellfun(@mean,A,'UniformOutput',false);
B = cellfun(@mean,B,'UniformOutput',false);
B = cellfun(@squeeze,B, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

the result here is:

B =

```
1×8 cell array

{91×1 double}    {91×1 double}    {91×1 double}    {91×1 double}    {91×1 double}    {91×1 double}    {91×1 double}    {91×1 double}
```

I am not sure what is the context of your data but assuming you want to find a single variance value for the whole 10x13 matrix you will need to flatten the matrix first before using function `var`.

```
for ii=8:-1:1
    flatA{ii} = reshape(A{ii}, 130, 91);
end

V = cellfun(@var, flatA, 'UniformOutput', false);
V = cellfun(@squeeze, V, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Artyom  but i need a 260x1 matrix at each cell in the 1x8 cell. i.e mean and variance combined like (M1 V1)....(Mn,Vn). Thanks